# Weird shading artifact caused by a non-planar N-Gon

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edges, artifacts

How to fix this weird gray area on my object?

What I meant by weird gray area is the slightly darker gray triangle above the curved edges. This is a shading artifact caused by a non-planar N-Gon.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to add topology to your object if you want to avoid this bad shading. To avoid a high-poly object you could then bake the normals

Comment: ohh okay thank you for the advice :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will notice that when you right click and set *Shade Flat*, the shading issue goes away. Setting it back to *Shade Auto Smooth*, introduces fake roundness which makes your n-gon non-planar thus creating this shading issue. I think even adding more topology will not solve the issue because of few vertices used for the entire circular part of the cylindrical shape.

[image]

You need to start with more vertices for the cylindrical part from the get go to support this type of curved window shape. I would start with a circle with 192 vertices and extrude that into the cylindrical shape. Add [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) for the top and bottom of window and then select its faces and use <kbd>I</kbd> to [`Inset Faces`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html) to build a nice [`Edge Loop`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) around the window that will help for cleaner topology.

[image]

Add the supporting Edge Loops for the Subdivision Modifier. This can be tricky because we don't want the Edge Loop to go upwards because it will create a similar shading issue:

[image]

Instead you have to manually move around Edges and Vertices to make the Edge Loop go parallel with the other one. Don't forget to <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* after you move vertices over each other.

[image]

Now you have very nice and clean quad topology:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much for the tutorial, its so helpful :)))